# Rupee sign(₹) overlaps in webpages

Tags: fonts, gui

Rupee symbol(₹) overlaps in webpages in Firefox and Chrome. There's no problem when there is a dollar symbol($).

[image: Screensot of https://workspace.google.co.in/intl/en_in/pricing.html in Firefox]

Comment: Maybe you miss a font which is capable of rendering the rupee sign correctly.

Comment: I chose English(India) After applying System wide there was no problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on *Region and Language* → *Manage Installed Languages*.
3. A new window titled *Language Support* will appear. Click on *Regional Formats*.
4. Choose *English (India)* and click on *Apply System-Wide*.

   [image: Screenshot of Language Support app]